# What happened to the dwarves of Nogrod and Belegost

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-silmarillion

In the Silmarillion, at the end of the First Age and after the War of Wrath, the cities of Nogrod and Belegost in the Blue Mountains "were utterly destroyed"

Did this include the populations of Dwarves, or were they evacuated first somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were likely some casualties, but at least some of the inhabitants made their way to Moria (emphasis mine):

> After the end of the First Age the power and wealth of Khazad-dûm was much increased; for **it was enriched by many people and much lore and craft when the ancient cities of Nogrod and Belegost in the Blue Mountains were ruined** at the breaking of Thangorodrim.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix A: "Annals of the Kings and Rulers" III "Durin's Folk"</sup>

According to Appendix B, this was a little ways into the Second Age:

> ***c.* 40** Many Dwarves leaving their old cities in Ered Luin<sup>1</sup> go to Moria and swell its numbers.
>
> <sup>*Return of the King* Appendix B: "The Tale of Years" *(i) The Second Age*</sup>

So it would appear that the destruction of the two cities wasn't quite as "utter" as all that. What exactly they were doing for those 40ish years, however, is unrecorded.

---

<sup>1</sup> The Blue Mountains; both Nogrod and Belegost were founded there

Comment: There was still a Dwarven settlement in the Blue Mountains into the Third Age (it was where Thorin lived prior to taking back Erebor).  That was presumably started by other survivors of Nogrod and Belegost.